# How to run a node.js app in background on Azure

Tags: node.js, azure, heroku

Say I have this simple nodejs app and want to deploy it to Azure as a `web app` to run in background:

```
//server.js
function test() {
    // send some request to a url
}
setInterval(test, 10000);
```

So I'd do this on Heroku by adding a `Procfile` and a command like `worker: node server.js`, but what's the equal method for azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Background tasks in Microsoft Azure App Service are called WebJobs. You can execute any of the following as a WebJob:

- .cmd, .bat,  .exe (using windows cmd)
- .ps1 (using powershell)
- .sh    (using bash)
- .php (using php)
- .py    (using python)
- **.js    (using node)**
- .jar    (using java)

You can read more about WebJobs on Microsoft Azure official documentation center:
[Run Background tasks with WebJobs](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/)

Also, Scott Allen has nice tutorial on node.js and WebJobs:
[Azure WebJobs With Node.js](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/04/07/azure-webjobs-with-node-js.aspx)